# Create new File(URI) with authority component

Tags: java

When running my java application from a network folder, I ran into an IllegalArgumentException that states: URI has an authority component.

I debugged and discovered the problem was that I was creating a new File by passing in a URI with an authority component. Previously, I had never encountered this problem because I had always run the application locally and there was no authority component.

```
URI uri = new URI("...network path...//myFile");
```

This throws an error:

```
File file = new File(uri);
```

This works:

```
File file = new File(uri.toString());
```

I see that inside the File(Uri) constructor it won't allow a URI with an authority component. Can any one explain why? and why I am allowed to create a file for a String?

Thanks!

Comment: `File(URI uri)` is a valid constructor for a File...

Comment: From the docs as well, which may help: Parameters:uri - An absolute, hierarchical URI with a scheme equal to "file", a non-empty path component, and undefined authority, query, and fragment components

Comment: Yes, I know that File can take a URI and I know that the URI cannot have an authority. I'm trying to figure out why that is. And why does creating File with a string path that is equivalent to the URI work?

Comment: Why that is? Because that's what the documentation specifies.

Answer (score 0):

The File class is for references to local files. It is for use with classes such as FileInputStream, which do not do network I/O and thus can not read remote files.